# MySQL - Where is the Error in this Query? (Error 1064)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to execute the query below but WorkBench keeps complaining about a syntax error (Error 1064). I don't know what the error is because even WorkBench highlights each bracket pair and so I can't say there is a missing bracket. Please help.

```
SELECT 
If(Right(Trim(`tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness`), 4) = 'susp', Substring(Trim(`tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness`), 1, Char_Length(Trim(Lower(`tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness`)) - 1)) ,Substring(Trim(Lower(`tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness`))))
FROM `tbloldfurniture`;
```

This is the same query broken into its separate parts to aid readability.

```
SELECT
    
    If(

        Right(Trim(`tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness`), 4) = 'susp', 

        Substring(Trim(`tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness`), 1, Char_Length(Trim(Lower(`tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness`)) - 1)) ,

        Substring(Trim(Lower(`tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness`)))
    )

FROM `tbloldfurniture`;
```

Comment: It would be great to create a fiddle to test 

Comment: This is the dbfiddle link. It also complains about a syntax error. - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=779b0b0b7b422b8ed6177d05a4dd9b5d

Comment: The fiddle lacks a create table statement. As to the problem: Replace `Trim(tbloldfurniture.NotesOnOldness)` by `'XXXXXX'` and `Trim(Lower(tbloldfurniture.NotesOnOldness))` by `'xxxxxx'`, and you'll probably see the errors :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's [`substring()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function expects at least two parameters and you're feeding it just one in `Substring(Trim(Lower(tbloldfurniture.NotesOnOldness)))`.

Also, you're probably doing something wrong, as you're deducting 1 from a string in `Char_Length(Trim(Lower(tbloldfurniture.NotesOnOldness)) - 1)`.

And yeah, SQL is notoriously terrible with its error messages. Confusing as heck.

Comment: SQL error messages are usually not that hard to understand, but MySQL seems to be an exception to that rule.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner not sure, I used to get awful error messages with PostgreSQL too.

Comment: @Robo Robok Thanks for point out the problem with Substring(Trim(Lower(tbloldfurniture.NotesOnOldness))). I have added the two missing parameters and it worked. - There was no error/complaint. Regarding the part where I deduct 1, it's fine because the Char_Length function is a numeric function. Same applies to the Length function.

Comment: @TheoFitchner the problem is with the parentheses - you probably meant `Char_Length(Trim(Lower(tbloldfurniture.NotesOnOldness))) - 1` (notice I moved the closing parenthesis).

Comment: You're right about the where the -1 should be. Much obliged.

Comment: @TheoFitchner by the way, I don't think it makes sense to use `lower()` just to count the characters. :)

Comment: @robo-robok Funny you mentioned this ahead of time. I only just used the code an hour ago and I realised that the lower() function is being ignored. The reason I'm trying to do it this way will be off-topic because the original problem (Error 1064/Syntax Error) has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The 1064 error is a syntax error. This means the reason there’s a problem is because MySQL doesn’t understand what you’re asking it to do. Cant see an issue with what you have put tho. If your  query attempts to reference information in a database and can’t find it, that could be the issue ?